# Moving WSUS DB To Another Drive

Tags: windows-server-2016, wsus

So I am moving the WID SUSDB from my C Drive to my E drive on my Windows Server 2016 server. I need to 
 make more room for other C Drive required software and items coming down the pike. Both are internal partitions on the same RAID 5 virtual disk.

I was able to go into the WID using SQL Management Studio and disconnect the SUSDB from WID. When I move the mdf and ldf files to the E Drive I gave the NT SERVICE\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID access to the folder the 2 files are in and I go back into WID with SQL and try an attach the file.

When I attach the Database at the MDF file it shows up in the database as Read Only. When I go to change it to read/write it says I don't have permission to make that change. It does that no matter where in I put it on the E Drive. Why am I not able to change that as the WSUS Admin and the Administrator of the machine? The files are not read only but all the folders on the E drive have that little dot on the Read only check box. Not a full check.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you trying to change the database to read/write in the object explorer of SQL Management Studio? Also, are you running the software as administrator?

Comment: @sippybear yes sir I am.